# Injection of dynamic directive/component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-di

I'm new to Angular 2 and thought I'd make an extendable master-detail flow to start learning.

The 'master'-part is working, I can easily plugin the specific service I need to populate the list when bootstrapping the app. The problem lies in making the 'detail'-part extendable.

Basically, the master-detail template has the following lines in the template:

```
<div class="large-10 columns">
    <detail [item]="masterItemActive" id="detail"></detail>
</div>
```

No, I could just load the `Detail` directive and be done with it, but I want that directive/component to be injectable so I could plugin whatever detail directive/component I like without hard-coding it into the 'master-detail'-component.

In order to achieve this I tried the `DynamicComponentLoader`:

```
dcl.loadAsRoot(detailComponent, '#detail', injector);
```

And the constructor of master-detail.component.ts:

```
constructor(
    dcl:DynamicComponentLoader,
    injector: Injector,
    elementRef:ElementRef,
    detailComponent:BaseDetailComponent
```

And as part of the bootstrap:

```
provide(BaseDetailComponent, {useValue: SomeSpecificDetailComponent})
```

The good news is that this works, it loads the `SomeSpecificDetailComponent` and shows the template where needed.

But now I'm stuck. Typescript is complaining, I cant seem to access the item passed down via `<detail [item]='masterItemActive'>` and I have no idea if this pattern is the way to go for finding a solution for this problem.

So my three questions are:

**Is the `DynamicComponentLoader` the way to go to solve this problem?**

Because I would much rather `provide()` a directive which the master-detail uses. This seems the most painless approach but I have no idea how to achieve this.

**How can I access the `item` inside `SomeSpecificDetailComponent`?**

I tried:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeSpecificDetailComponent extends BaseDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    item:BaseMasterItem; // always empty (and yes, masterItemActive is being set )
}
```

**And how can I prevent typescript from complaining?**

Because the first argument of `dcl.loadAsRoot()` needs to be of type 'Type' - which it isn't.

```
Argument of type 'BaseDetailComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update**

I've been wrongly using `Type` as an interface, the typescript compilation error was fixed by using `BaseDetailComponent extends Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to dynamically injected components or directives is currently not supported.

What you can do is to pass the data imperatively to the created component

```
dcl.loadAsRoot(detailComponent, '#detail', injector)
.then(componentRef => componentRef.instance.item = this.masterItemActive);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Too bad it isn't supported, the approach feels a bit hackish.  Do you know if they plan to support it?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't seen any comments in favor or against it. Everyone wants it though AFAIK.

Comment: Is there a Guthub issue for that?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I think so.